# Output the source of a ruby method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Say I make a class with a method in it.

```
class A
  def test
    puts 'test'
  end
end
```

I want to know what goes on inside of `test`. I want to literally output:

```
def test
  puts 'test'
end
```

Is there any way to output the source of a method in a string?

Comment: This isn't clear: "I want to know what goes on inside of test." Do you want to single-step the method in the debugger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) to view methods

```
# myfile.rb
require 'pry'
class A
   def test
     return 'test'
   end
end
puts Pry::Method(A.new.method(:test)).source      #(1)
# or as suggested in the comments
puts Pry::Method.from_str("A#test").source        #(2)
# uses less cpu cycles than #(1) because it does not call initialize - see comments
puts Pry::Method(A.allocate.method(:test)).source #(3)
# does not use memory to allocate class as #(1) and #(3) do
puts Pry::Method(A.instance_method(:test)).source      #(4)
```

Then run `ruby myfile.rb` and you will see:

```
def test
   return 'test'
end
```

Comment: There is no need to use `binding.pry`  Just run the command `pry` and use `load "a.rb"` then use the `show-method A#test` method.  It will show.  Here is the source code: [Pry's show-source](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/master/lib/pry/commands/show_source.rb#L7)

Comment: @KaiKönig you can make it easier still, use this: `Pry::Method.from_str("A#test").source`

Comment: `puts Pry::Method(A.allocate.method(:test)).source` Is better than using `new` as it doesn't rely on knowing the signature, just the name.  But I like banisters answer even better, it only relies on it being there.

Comment: @vgoff why create a new instance at all? unbound method objects are fine, too :) `Pry::Method(A.instance_method(:test)).source`

Comment: Indeed.  I have used this with ObjectSpace to document all methods dynamically for an object.  It even documents the dynamic ones.

Comment: Any idea how I could reflect the contents of a Sinatra `get` method? `get '/foo' { "output" }`?