# Getting the last line of a method definition

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is there a way to know the location of the last line of a method definition without parsing the source code using a parser (other than the one running under the Ruby implementation itself) or regex or any external library that does that?

It is easy to get the first line of a method definition by using the information provided by `set_trace_func` or `method_added` since they are triggered at the moment of a method definition, and I can analyze the information provided (directly from `set_trace_func` or parsing the `caller` information from `method_added`).

But for the last line of a method definition, the best I can do is to look for the first line of the next method definition or other `call`s detected by `set_trace_func`. I can tell that the original method definition has ended by this line, but cannot tell whether it ended in a line earlier than that. For example, suppose I am trying to get the last line of the definition of method `foo`. In a case where the source code is like below:

```
   | def foo
   |   ...
n  | end; def bar
   |   ...
```

given that the first line of `bar` definition is `n`, I can (coincidentally) tell that the last line of `foo` definition is `n`. But if the source code happened to be like below:

```
     | def foo
     |   ...
n-1  | end
n    | def bar
```

then I want to get `n-1` as the last line of `foo`, and I cannot figure out a way to tell that it is `n-1` in this case and not `n`. The source code may further have empty/comment lines like this:

```
     | def foo
     |   ...
n-9  | end
     | 
     | # comment
     | 
     | =begin
     |   ...
     | =end
     | 
n-1  | 
n    | def bar
```

and it is not a big problem that I still get `n-1` instead of the correct `n-9`, but getting `n` instead is a big problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It might be there's deeper magic in Ruby's interpreter you can tap into that'll have that information.

Comment: @theTinMan I wrote a software in Ruby that reads a Ruby file and generates an html file that makes it easier to navigate through the code. For each method definition and constant assignment, it displays the information extracted from the source such as the list of arguments (for methods) or the value (for constants) and the corresponding part of source code. I am looking for a robust and a non-redundant way. If you can show any direction, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know how to obtain the number of the first line of a method, all you need is [the number of lines the method's definition has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698768/output-the-source-of-a-ruby-method). You add the former to the latter and you've got the number of the last line.

Let's adapt the example from the linked question to inspect `Set#add`.

```
require 'pry'
require 'set'
number_of_lines = Pry::Method.from_str("Set#add").source.lines.count
```

As noted by [Pry's author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66725/banister), Pry uses Ruby's built-in parser to extract source code.

Comment: How do you get the number of lines?

Comment: Doesn't pry use regex to parse the source?

Comment: @sawa Pry doesn't use regex, it uses ruby's built-in parser to extract the source.

Comment: @banister It is thankful to have comments from the author. I was reading around lines 78--80 in https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/master/lib/pry/module_candidate.rb. Am I looking for the wrong place? Can you point me to the location where pry extracts the source code? I am curious to see how it is done.

Comment: @sawa `module_candidate.rb` is used to extract the source for a class/module, not a method. and it only uses regex to find the start of the class definition, not to actually extract the source. We use the `method_source` gem (which i wrote too) to get the source of a method, the relevant lines are found here: https://github.com/banister/method_source/blob/master/lib/method_source/code_helpers.rb#L20-L41